# How can I stop a Wordpress blog from constantly reblogging all my content?

Tags: wordpress

A Wordpress blog keeps reblogging word-for-word, and image-for-image the content of my site. Apparently Wordpress has a "reblog" function which makes it extremely easy to do.

Is there a way to disable this function, or at least make it tougher or more time-consuming to copy-paste my content?

Comment: Are you talking about self hosted wordpress or wordpress.com?

Answer (score 0):

The Wordpress re-blog feature should not grab an entire post, unless it's less than 85(ish) words.

With that said, it's still annoying and there might be a way to partially block your content. I haven't tested but I believe "re-blog" grabs the first image in a post, so if you placed a transparent pixel before your content, there is a chance they might pick that up instead.

Worth a shot, but I'm not aware of a way to completely avoid this scraping.

Unless your blog is posted onto images :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure they are using reblog function?
It's also easy for them to grab entire posts using your RSS feed, and that's been happening for a long time.
You can see if that's the case by switching your RSS feed setting to partial.